# Non-stationary time series model

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

I recently have a task related to non-stationary model in time series but I'm running out of ideas how to solve it, may be someone can help?

I am tasked to find the auto-covariance for the model 
$$
W_t=Z_t - Z_{t-1}
$$ 
where $Z_t$ is an AR(1) model with parameters $-1<\phi_1<1$ and $\sigma^2$. And in particular, I must verify that the variance of $W_t$ is $2\sigma^2/(1 + \phi_1)$.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything that I edited incorrectly.

Comment: @Taylor Thank you for your help, It looks better now. What did you use to convert it into mathematical form? Is there any way I can do the same via phone (android)?

Comment: @user24024 it's called $\LaTeX$ (pronounced "lay-tek"). There are expressions you can type that usually start with a backslash that can get rendered as mathematical symbols. Click "edit" on your post and you can see what I typed.

Comment: @The Laconic I found out the model above has the similar pattern with The random walk model, so I tried to solve it by modifying it with nonzero constant term but I couldn't get any further. I also tried with standard AR 1 form, then calculate the expectation value in order to find the auto-covariance but useless.

Comment: @Taylor Okay, I'll try it later in my laptop. Anyway, do you have any idea how to solve the problem above?

Answer (score 1):

A hint: bilinearity of $\operatorname{Cov}(\cdot,\cdot)$.

For the $Z_t$ series, 
\begin{align*}
\gamma_Z(h) &= \operatorname{Cov}(Z_{t+h},Z_t) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(\phi Z_{t+h-1} + \epsilon_{t+h},Z_t) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(\phi Z_{t+h-1} ,Z_t) \\
&= \phi \gamma_Z(h-1).
\end{align*}
and it is usually assumed that $\gamma_Z(0) = \operatorname{Var}(Z_1) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1- \phi^2}$.

For the $W_t$ series:
\begin{align*}
\gamma_W(h) &= \operatorname{Cov}(W_{t+h},W_t) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(Z_{t+h} - Z_{t+h-1},Z_t-Z_{t-1}) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(Z_{t+h},Z_t) - \operatorname{Cov}(Z_{t+h},Z_{t-1}) - \operatorname{Cov}(Z_{t+h-1},Z_{t}) + \operatorname{Cov}(Z_{t+h-1},Z_{t-1})\\
&= \gamma_Z(h) - \gamma_Z(h+1) - \gamma_Z(h-1) + \gamma_Z(h) \\
&= 2\gamma_Z(h) - \gamma_Z(h+1) - \gamma_Z(h-1).
\end{align*}